# How to make a thread race program?

Tags: java, multithreading

A have to make a thread race program, where a ThreadRace class will create an instance of 10 ThreadRaceCompetitor's. Then it'll run them all. There will be a results class called ThreadRaceContext, which will keep the scorecard of who finished in which place.

When a ThreadRaceCompetitor finishes the race, it will have to inform the ThreadRaceContext his race number (an id), and that it's done. The ThreadRaceContext will list the final rankings to the console

Comment: Hi, perhaps this might be of use https://www.baeldung.com/java-start-thread

Comment: are the threads required to do any work or delay for random time or just get spawned and then notify when complete and the other class notes the time and by which thread it was notified.

Comment: @mavriksc the threads just have to announce when they are complete and the over class must note all the results.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use separate classes but is functionally the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Map<Integer, Date> results = new HashMap<>();
    IntStream.range(0,10).parallel().forEach(i->results.put(i,new Date()));
    Thread.sleep(30);
    results.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value.getTime()));
}
```

but with no delay they appear to end all at the same time

> 0 1559767161100
>   1 1559767161100
>   2 1559767161100
>   3 1559767161100
>   4 1559767161100
>   5 1559767161100
>   6 1559767161100
>   7 1559767161100
>   8 1559767161100
>   9 1559767161100

even doing 100 they all finish at the same time, even doing some simple math before timestamping.adding a delay for each thread does then cause the times to be different. i think the computers are just too fast for there to be a difference in the millis .

*edit: to add delays i declare the `results` as static outside before main then

```
private static void doStuff(int i) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    results.put(i,new Date());
}
```

and change `IntStream.range(0,10).parallel().forEach(i->results.put(i,new Date()));` to `IntStream.range(0,10).parallel().forEach(i->doStuff(i));`

Comment: that's awesome!
How would be the alternative with delays?